# Internal server error deployment on Azure - node.js and Vue.js

Tags: node.js, azure, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have been looking all over the internet for two weeks now and I have no clue what is happening.

I have an app running on a node.js server. The app uses the Vue.js framework and Vuetify.js, so I don't have a "traditional" js server. The website works perfectly on local, but every time I try and deploy it on an Azure (Windows) web application (per request from the company I am developing for), the only thing that is displayed is this: " *The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred*. ".

I did set the Azure Web App to use node.js as instructed on the official documentation.

According to my searches, it is probably a problem with my web.config file, but I can't seem to solve it, so would be really happy if someone could help me out here.

What I have tried so far:

- multiple versions of the Web.config file
- opening the 443 and 80 port on the Azure Web App to rule out any kind of conflict there
- moving around my Vue classes to try and solve a problem there
- making the front end in HTML files and in Vue files. Right now it is back into Vue files

I can't seem to find what else to try and would be really grateful if anyone had a solution!

I can add my web.config here if needed

Thanks in advance!